# Github API works in curl but not python - bad credentials

Tags: github, authorization, github-api

I am trying to use the Github API and it works when I do curl from terminal but not when using the Python Request library:

WORKS:

```
curl -v --location --request GET 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=500+created:2017-01-01&order=asc&per_page=100' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN'
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
import requests

url = https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=500+created:2017-01-01&order=asc&per_page=100
r = requests.get(url, auth=(MY_GITHUB_USERNAME, MY_TOKEN))
```

I get the following response for python:

" b'{"message":"Bad credentials","documentation_url":"https://docs.github.com/rest"}' "

Would appreciate any help - thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below snippet, you have to send PAT in header,

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=stars:>=500+created:2017-01-01&order=asc&per_page=100"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
  
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Check the documentation
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you going I think. Think it is just the headers that needed a little bit of a change.

```
import requests

token = MYTOKEN
url = "some url"

headers = {"Accept": "application/vnd.github.html",
           "Authorization": f"token {token}",}

request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```