# Using Python request with GitHub API fails with Bad credentials

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

I been trying to generate a Token for self-hosted machines using the GitHub-API for my Org.

Using Curl it works as expected from GitHubs [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/self-hosted-runners?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-registration-token-for-an-organization)

```
curl -L \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <MY-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/<MY-ORG>/actions/runners/registration-token
```

response

```
{
  "token": "RUNNER_TOKEN",
  "expires_at": "2023-09-01T23:47:56.042+02:00"
}
```

Then I tried to re-create this is Python, using the requests lib

```py
def get_runner_token(token, org):
    url = f"https://api.github.com/orgs/{org}/actions/runners/registration-token"
    authorization = f'Bearer {token}' # Tried both as Bearer and token
    headers = CaseInsensitiveDict() # Tried as normal dict as well
    headers['Accept'] = "application/vnd.github+json" # Tried removing accept and API version
    headers['Authorization'] = authorization
    headers['X-GitHub-Api-Version'] = "2022-11-28"
    payload = {} #Tried with and without payload...
    print("Sending request to", url, "with headers", headers)
    x = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    print(x, x.json())
```

No matter what I do I keep getting the response

```
<Response [401]> {'message': 'Bad credentials', 'documentation_url': 'https://docs.github.com/rest'}
```

If don't send the token as an arg through a function like so:

```py
def get_runner_token(org):
    token = "..."
    # Same as code above....
```

It works? I don't understand
Can anybody see what I might be doing wrong?

While very similar to [Github API works in curl but not python - bad credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71071281/github-api-works-in-curl-but-not-python-bad-credentials). None of the answers worked for me

Comment: Your code works for me as written (specifically, [this code](https://gist.github.com/larsks/34692e5369327c5f234e3e8a72054ff0), with `org` and `token` filled out with appropriate values).

Comment: @larsks Okay, if I do just what you did it also work. But if I do what I actually doing (sending them in as args to a function). It does not work?
So looks like the error is not where I thought it was. I'll update my question with the more correct code (question updated)

Comment: @larsks After even more attempts to figure our what went wrong. It seems that some extra (invisible) characters got added when I copied the token to the (windows) terminal when calling the python function. So the token was wrong. Was not until i compared the one copied in code and the one sent from the terminal that I noticed it. So thank you for indirectly solving my problem